# Spring rest. Abstract JSON tree payload

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Is there any way to get abstract JSON payload as a parameter of the Spring rest controller method. I want something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Bean method(JsonNode requestRaw)
```

`JsonNode` is the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`

Node is too complex, `Map<String, Object>` is not quiet convenient.

Thank you!

Comment: Create a bean/pojo object with similar structure and use your object instead of JsonNode. (Although it's trivial but if you can post your json structure, we can suggest a pojo structure).

Comment: JSON has irregular structure. And there are several schemes. I need a way to process abstract tree. This question is mainly about handling some random JSON. In my case some fields may be presented or not. And there is no meta info about class and type. Regular bean or schema can not help.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Jackson as your JSON provider and take advantage of its Tree Model: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes